# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I just realized that [one of my questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/57323/11980) posted on this SE got silently deleted ([SE should really notify posters when their content is erased](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694/178179)...). Why was the question off-topic? Doesn't that fall under printing in the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section? I was exporting some  Adobe Illustrator document to PDF to prepare for printing.

---

Subject: Object pushed to back upon export to PDF in Adobe Illustrator

Body:

> I inserted a vector graphic in my Adobe Illustrator document:
>
> [image]
>
> Then I exported the Adobe Illustrator document to PDF, and opened the
>   exported PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI, where I saw that the vector
>   graphic is not visible (screenshot taken as I was using the "Edit Text
>   & Images" tool in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI):
>
> [image]
>
> This surprises me as I made sure that the image was at the front in
>   Adobe Illustrator:
>
> [image]
>
> Yet in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI I had to bring to font to make the image
>   appear:
>
> [image]
>
> Why?
>
> I use Adobe Acrobat Pro XI and Adobe Illustrator CC 17.0.0 64-bit with
>   Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: No idea. Seeing your stats in the other stacks, you certainly know what is a good question. I guess it was considered "tech support" and maybe you got no questions asked to you before it was voted to be closed... Personally I'd like to help on this but I'd probably need to see some parts of the ai file. It's a weird issue but there's probably an easy solution for this (maybe flattening the layers and see if there's any changes.)

Comment: *SE should really notify posters when their content is erased* – More importantly, [SE should inform you when your question gets closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/255554).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft yes also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does appear to be closed as off-topic technical support. That generally refers to issues with software which can really only be addressed by the software manufacturer, in this case Adobe.

> "This appears to be a tech support question about fixing technology to work as advertised. Please edit the question so that it pertains to using technology to solve a design problem. You may want to check if it hasn't already been asked in Super User. In many cases, contacting the manufacturer is the quickest option." – Scott, Johannes, Zach Saucier, Benteh, Vincent

You're question was asking how to fix an issue with a application, not solve a design problem. The issue was not a "I don't know enough" issue. It is clearly a "this application is not working as expected" issue.

No one here can generally trouble-shoot technical issues without knowing your operating system, application versions, and other *localized* items. Therefore, it's off topic. Essentially as soon as you need to mention "Windows" (or Mac for that matter) you've created an off-topic question.

Yes there are some *older questions from the beta* still hanging around that skirt the tech-support issue. So while you may find some references here to operating systems and application issues, most won't be any newer than 2012 or 2013.

As for why it was *deleted*.... "Community" is a site-bot for all stack sites. It cleans up, closes, edits, and deletes posts for various reasons. One reason is a question, with no up votes and no answers with votes which has been placed on hold. This is done to keep the overall site free of unneeded content.

As for a notice that the question was deleted or closed... that's more a stack business model question which I can't answer. However, you **should** have gotten a site message that the question was placed on hold. If you failed to respond within (I think) a few days, then the question was subject to deletion.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks, I didn't whether it was by designed or some bug. I still think maybe some user might have found some workaround, which would be interesting to share on this SE.  Yes this damn roomba and no notification policy unfortunately present in all SEs.

Comment: Whether or not a user here *may* be able to answer it is irrelevant. It is not within the scope defined for this stack. I can answer some questions on auto-repair... but they don't belong here either.

Comment: ok sounds good, I'll transfer to superuser then